# Password reset Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hi is it possible to make reset password page on Oracle apex on autonomus database. I read all topics and none of them works. It seems that have to be custom authorization, on this classic authorization system i don't find way. It should be trivial thing, at least it is in other technologies as Laravel etc. I m trying all day to fix this up.
I tried with triggers to make calls on htmldb_util apis, tried  dbms scheduled jobs. Every time I get error "You have to have admin privileges".
And when I want to give APEX_ADMIN_ROLE to user I got error role doesn't exist but it exists in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible for all who wants this , admin should give privileges to execute and create scheduled jobs, then make job to call procedure to reset. I read about solutions that sys should make job but it is wrong. Schema user connected on workspace should make scheduled job.